# How to use installed libs in jupyter lab?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I'm running jupyter lab, not notebook.

I'm trying to use libs like lens, featuretools.
I have them installed, but running:

```
pip install lens
```

tells me `"requirement already satisfied"`

But

`import lens`

tells me

```
"no module named lens"
```

is it because jupyter lab runs somewhere else on remote server, not on my local pc(like jupyter notebook) 
so it can't detect the libs on my machine? do i have to install the libs on this remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter Lab and Jupyter Notebook is not the difference that matters here: they are different **views** of the same Jupyter **environment** behind the scenes. It's whether your Jupyter session is remote or local that matters. A remote Jupyter environment cannot look at what packages you have installed on your computer; they are completely separate environments.

When you run Jupyter locally, it uses the packages installed in your local environment (i.e., the one you ran Jupyter from). You can also configure it to use other environments on your system by using a package like `nb_conda_kernels` (https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels).

When you use a remote Jupyter, what environment you get depends on how the administrator set up that system. You should look at the documentation for your system and/or contact the administrator of the system to ask how to install packages.

As a quick fix, you might be able to open the integrated terminal in your Jupyter environment and run `pip install`, or perhaps `pip install --user` from there. Whether this will work depends on how the administrator has set up the environment. You may need to do this again every time you start a new session.